# Not possible to use Table aliases in Quarkus / Mutiny SqlClient?

Tags: java, kotlin, quarkus, mutiny

I'm new to Quarkus and actually really excited to use it in my next project. One of my first steps was to configure a mysql connection and perform queries on it in a reactive way as shown [here](https://quarkus.io/guides/reactive-sql-clients). I didn't want to use JPA/Hibernate so I didn't go for the Panache way.

But what I found out was that I can't use table aliases while mapping the rowset.

```
val sql = "SELECT u.id, u.name, u.created_at, u.edited_at FROM user AS u WHERE id = ?"
val params = Tuple.of(request.id)
    
return client.preparedQuery(sql).execute(params)
             .onItem().transform { rowSet ->
                 rowSet.firstOrNull().let { row ->
                    row?.let {
                         User.fromRow(it)
                     }
                   }
               }

...

return User(
    id = UUID.fromString(row.getString("u.id")), //Not working !! I only can parse from `id` not from `u.id` :(
    name = row.getString("u.name"),
    createdAt = row.getLocalDateTime("u.created_at").toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC),
    editedAt = row.getLocalDateTime("u.edited_at").toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC)
)
```

This is really frustrating since queries including complex joins will not be possible when the column names are ambiguous (e.g id is a very common column name).

Is there a way to change this behavior or is it just a bug?
`Im using Quarkus 1.13.0.Final with the quarkus-reactive-mysql-client dependency`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Table aliases works but if you want to have a dot (`.`) in the alias you have to escape it:

```
val sql = "SELECT u.id as `u.id`," +
                " u.name as `u.name`," +
                " u.created_at as `u.created_at`," +
                " u.edited_at as `u.edited_at`" + 
         " FROM user AS u WHERE id = ?"
```